# A click noise is happening at the end of the Audio playing.

Tags: android, audio, soundpool

I am having a couple problems I could really use some help on both. The first is I am trying to get an audio file to play when the application is started and as soon as the shake occurs it stops. (It is not playing it at all on either screen it is supposed to). The other issue I am having is when I shake the phone an audio is supposed to play. It is doing just that, but the problem is that at the end of the audio playing it make a pop sound. That noise isn't on the audio files so I am not exactly sure where that sound is coming from. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
public class Ask extends Activity{
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
 private ShakeEventListener mSensorListener;
 String[] answer;
 int possibleAnswers, randomAnswer, talkRun=0;
 long lastClick;


 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ask);

        final Random generator = new Random();




        //Sounds
        final SoundPool sounds = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        final int sound0 = sounds.load(this, R.raw.coughing, 1);

        final int sound25 = sounds.load(this, R.raw.askbud, 1);


        sounds.play(sound25, 1f, 1f, 1, 0, 1f);

        mSensorListener = new ShakeEventListener();
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(mSensorListener,
            mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);

      final TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.answer);


        mSensorListener.setOnShakeListener(new ShakeEventListener.OnShakeListener() {

          public void onShake() {
              if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastClick > 500) {
                  lastClick = System.currentTimeMillis();
                      sounds.stop(sound25);
                    sounds.stop(sound0);


                      randomAnswer = generator.nextInt(possibleAnswers);


                      if(randomAnswer==0){
                         sounds.play(sound0, 1f, 1f, 1, 0, 1f);
                      }

              }
          }
        });
    }





 @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(mSensorListener,
        mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
        SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onStop() {
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mSensorListener);
    super.onStop();
  }
```

}

Comment: Wow! That's a whole heapin' helpin' of code to digest.  Did it never occur to you to get it working for one sound before dumping code to the site that fails for 25 separate sounds?  Also, I do not approve of adding the 'java' tag here.  In Java, you'd use JavaSound to play sounds - Android is a whole different story.

Comment: The sounds (except for the onCreate one ) all play. The only problem with the others I am having is the pop noise at the end of the sound. And I am just wondering if anyone else has come across this problem at some point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by switching from using sound pool to using media player. Also got to make sure to release() or it was causing other problems like the sound stopped playing.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this sound click problem (or pop as you call it) at the end of the sounds I was playing. My files were .wav files then, but he click sound disappeared after I converted the sound files to .ogg.
I was experiencing this on the Android emulator.

Answer (score 0):

its not working in the on create because sounds are not loaded yet when you call play here

```
sounds.play(sound25, 1f, 1f, 1, 0, 1f);
```

please look at

```
public void setOnLoadCompleteListener (SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener listener)
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html#setOnLoadCompleteListener(android.media.SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener)